# reading xml with android 

Tags: android, xml

I need to build an app on android which read data from a windows based software built in vb.

How would I do this?. Is using XML is good option. If yes then How to read xml with android?

Answer (score 3):

You can use xml, json or a number of other formats.

I found using [XmlPullParser](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html) to be easy for parsing xml. Included in that link is sample code.

I also had a good experience using [gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) to parse json.

Answer (score 0):

If you know how to parse XML in any other language just go from there. You should decide on SAX/DOM. There are various frameworks for parsing XML depending on your specific needs. Have a look around and pick the one that fits best.

(Any Java XML Framework will do)

Answer (score 0):

Your best option parsing XML on an Android device is using Simple Framework. It uses annotations to do the mapping XML <--> Object.
Most of the XML frameworks are not Android friendly (like JAXB or XMLBeans)

You can find a good example here: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/02/android-xml-binding-simple-tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

I parse my xml streams with the DocumentBuilderFactory

```
 Document doc = null;
 DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
 DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
 doc = db.parse(inputstream);
```

your can read the xml like:

```
org.w3c.dom.Node parent_node = doc.getElementsByTagName("TagName").item(0);
NodeList nl = parent_node.getChildNodes();
for(int i = 0;i<nl.getLength();i++){
    String path = nl.item(i).getFirstChild().getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
    String [] pairs = path.split(" ");
            ....
```

Answer (score 0):

As hut suggested the Absolute best way to work with XML in Android is to use the [Simple XML Library](http://simple.sourceforge.net/). You can take a look at my tutorial for including Simple in your Android project: [its on my blog](http://massaioli.homelinux.com/wordpress/2011/04/21/simple-xml-in-android-1-5-and-up/).